# BeanPropertyRowMapper when mapping for field not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a repository class that calls `jdbcTemplate` `query()` and uses `BeanPropertyRowMapper(..)`

```
@Override
public List<Model> query(final Model model) {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(
            this.QUERY.replace("${WHERE}", this.queryBuilder.build(model)),
            new PostGrePropertyMapper(model)
                    .addProperty("test", new TestMapper().apply(model.getTest())),
            new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Model.class));
}
```

Say I have this model (it has many fields but for demo shortened to 3):

```
public class Model {
    private String test;
    private String id;
    private String reference;
}
```

and the query returns me two columns: `test` & `id` in the ResultSet. 
Is there a way I can set the value of the `reference` field to that of `id` that is being returned from database? The `id` and `reference` should be set off the `id` field coming from DB.

Where can I set this value for `reference` without having to write a custom row mapper and setting each and every field with `rs.getString(...)` calls.

Is there a short technique for such scenario?

Comment: you can use ifnull in your select part. i.e SELECT IFNULL(reference, id), id, test;

Comment: I deliberately don’t provide it. The idea is to use id from sql to map to two java model fields

Answer (score 0):

The shortest technique is to fix the query so that it matches the model:

```
SELECT test, id, id as reference FROM ...
```